# PHP SQL Truncate

Tags: php, sql, database, truncate

I'm having a problem trying to truncate the 'requestID' field from my requests table.

This is my code.

```
<?php
        include 'mysql_connect.php';
     USE fypmysqldb;
     TRUNCATE TABLE requestID;
     echo "Request ID table has been truncated";     
?>
```

I'm using server side scripting so no idea what error is coming back.

Anyone got an idea?

Comment: That isn't valid PHP.  In mysql_connect.php, what method are you using, mysql_connect, PDO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't executing queries, you're just putting SQL code inside PHP which is invalid. This assumes you are using the `mysql_*()` api (which I kind of suspect after viewing one of your earlier questions), but can be adjusted if you are using MySQLi or PDO.

```
 // Assuming a successful connection was made in this inclusion:
 include 'mysql_connect.php';
 // Select the database
 mysql_select_db('fypmysqldb');
 // Execute the query.
 $result = mysql_query('TRUNCATE TABLE requestID');

 if ($result) {
   echo "Request ID table has been truncated";  
 }
 else echo "Something went wrong: " . mysql_error();
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the function [`mysql_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) which performs the query execution. The code to execute a query should look something like this.

```
$link = mysql_connect('host', 'username', 'password') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("fypmysqldb", $link) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("TRUNCATE TABLE requestID", $link) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_close($link);
```